# Relativization results in class separation

Tags: complexity-theory

We know that $P\neq NP$ problem cannot be demonstrated by relativization because there exists oracle relative to which they are equal.

Is there natural complexity classes that has been shown to be equal but are separate under some oracle?

Comment: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/papers/roh/roh.pdf $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer This is very weird though. Things that are equal can be separated by oracles.

Comment: yes relativization is quite a tricky concept. see eg survey [role of relativization in complexity theory](https://www.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/relative.pdf) by fortnow. there are also some cutting edge [new results](http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.03398) by Rossman et al on PH.

Comment: see also [validity of oracles in math arguments](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/34080/how-is-it-valid-to-use-oracles-in-mathematical-arguments)

Comment: @Turbo There is equal, and there is equal.  When we write IP=PSPACE, we mean that the set of problems in PSPACE is equal to the set of problems in IP.  But IP is not equal to PSPACE in terms of how they are defined.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, check out the classes [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_%28complexity%29) (interactive polynomial time) and [PSPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE) (polynomial space).

In 1988, Fortnow and Sipser [1] showed  that these two classes have contradictory relativizations, that is, there exist oracles $A$ and $B$ ($A$ can be chosen to be $\text{PSPACE}$ itself) such that
$$\text{IP}^A = \text{PSPACE}^A\text{, and}$$
$$\text{IP}^B \neq \text{PSPACE}^B .$$

Later, Shamir [2] showed that $\text{IP} = \text{PSPACE}$.

Chang et al. furthermore showed that for a random oracle $A$, $\text{IP}^A \neq \text{PSPACE}^A$ [3].  See *ibid.* for a nice introduction and overview.
This result actually disproves *the Random Oracle Hypothesis* which states that

> the relationships between complexity classes which hold for almost all oracles must also hold in the unrelativized case [3].

**References**

[1] Fortnow, L. & Sipser, M., **Are there interactive protocols for co-NP languages?**, Inform. Process. Lett. 28, No. 5 (1988), 249-251.

[2] Shamir, A. **IP = PSPACE**, in "Proceedings, IEEE Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science, 1990," pp. 11-15.

[3] Chang, R., Chor, B., Goldreich, O., Hartmanis, J., Håstad, J., Ranjan, D., & Rohatgi, P. (1994). **The random oracle hypothesis is false**. Journal of Computer and System Sciences, 49(1), 24-39.